# cesium 3D model orientation and rolling

Tags: 3d, cesiumjs

I'm new at Cesium and I have a 3D model, I display it as below:

```
this.model = scene.primitives.add(Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
  url : './assets/cesium/myPlane.glb',
  modelMatrix : modelMatrix,
  minimumPixelSize : 128,
  maximumScale : 20000
}));
```

1. how do I change the 'rolling' of the model (it display upside down)
2. how do I change its 'head' to be wame direction as moovingf direction (if plane move to the left so its head will change angle to left)

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: Some questions: What is `modelMatrix` defined to be, and can you omit that?  Is the GLB file a glTF 1.0 or 2.0 file?  Does the model follow glTF orientation conventions (+Y up, +Z forward in 2.0)?

Comment: Also you're using `scene.primitives`, any reason you need that over an Entity?  I ask because entities have a helper function called `VelocityOrientationProperty` that might do what you want, see line 70 of the [Interpolation Demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Interpolation.html).

Comment: I saw this Demo but I didnt understand how to modify it for my needs.
I need 3 things:
1. provide long,lat,alt to the plane and plane will move to that location. 
2. have the abillity to controll plane orientantion (so it will point to the right flight direction)
3. move camera to plane location (so I can track it / untrack it by a button click)

Comment: @emackey can you help here?

Comment: I think you're asking too much for one question.  Myself and other folks on Stack Overflow can't write the app for you, which is what it sounds like you're asking for in the comments.  SO has guidelines on this.  Try writing a stand-alone sample that shows as much as you can manage of what's needed, then find a specific problem or error in that sample to post a question about.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your model is not properly aligned with Cesium's axes convention. You have two options:

1. Re-orient your model in the modelling software (blender, 3ds max, etc).
2. Introduce an intermediate coordinate system that re-orients the model within your app (needs a bit of math though).

My suggestion is to try the first option and if that should not work or you cannot modify your models, try the second one.

Hint: For debugging your models in Cesium, the [inspector](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/viewerCesiumInspectorMixin.html) really helps, as you can show the reference frame. Here is a [sandbox](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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) of what your model should look like:

[image: inspector: model axes]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can load your model as a czml and set orientation. See below :

```
    var position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(<lon>, <lat>, <alt>);
    var pheading = Cesium.Math.toRadians(<heading>);
    var pitch = Cesium.Math.toRadians(0);
    var roll = Cesium.Math.toRadians(0);
    var hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(pheading, pitch, roll);
    var orientation = new Cesium.ConstantProperty(Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(position, hpr));


    var czml = [
        {
            "id": "document",
            "name": "CZML Model",
            "version": "1.0"

        }, {
            "id": id,
            "name": id,

            "position": {
                "cartographicDegrees": [
                    lon, lat, alt
                ]
            },

            "model": {

                "gltf": <gltfpath>



            }

        }
    ];

    var promise = olcesium.nc.viewer.dataSources.add(Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load(czml));
    promise.orientation = orientation;
    promise.then(function (dataSource) {

        for (var i = 0; i < dataSource.entities.values.length; i++) {
            dataSource.entities.values[i].orientation = orientation;
        }

    });
```